# Скалярное произведение векторов, SSE

Tags: c++

Помогите с примером скалярного произведения двух векторов, заданных массивами типа `double`, при помощи SSE инструкций. Все найденные мной примеры почему-то написаны для типа `float`.
Например, вот такая функция

```
float inner(int n, float* x, float* y)
{
    __m128 *xx = (__m128*)x;
    __m128 *yy = (__m128*)y;
    __m128 s = _mm_setzero_ps();

    for(int i=0; i<n/4; ++i)
    {
        __m128 p = _mm_mul_ps(xx[i],yy[i]);
        s = _mm_add_ps(s,p);
    }
    __m128 p = _mm_movehl_ps(p,s);
    s = _mm_add_ps(s,p);
    p = _mm_shuffle_ps(s,s,1);
    s = _mm_add_ss(s,p);
    float sum;
    _mm_store_ss(&sum,s);
    return sum;
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

А здесь ничего сложного нет. Просто нужно поменять команды на другие. Double вдвое больше по размеру, чем float, поэтому цикл нужно вести до `n/2`, а не до `n/4`, далее, ищите справочник и команды работы с double. Например, `_mm_mul_pd` - это умножение double, аналогично, скорее всего, `_mm_add_pd` будет для сложения. Аналогично можно отыскать в гугле остальные команды, у меня на это ушло 5 минут.

UPD: лучше после цикла не делать эту ерунду, что написана в примере, а лучше командой `_mm_store_pd` сохранить два double из xmm регистра в две переменные и спокойно вернуть их сумму.

Comment: Попробовал, вот что получилось 
`__m128d *xx = (__m128d*)x;
 __m128d *yy = (__m128d*)y;
 __m128d s = _mm_setzero_pd();

 for (int i = 0; i < n / 2; ++i)
 {
  __m128d p = _mm_mul_pd(xx[i], yy[i]);
  s = _mm_add_pd(s, p);
 } 
 double s1, s2;
 _mm_store_sd(&s1, s);
 _mm_store_sd(&s2, s);
 return s1 + s2;`
Ответ получается верный, но что-то не то с памятью

Comment: Бегло взглянув на код, я подумал, что вы неверно пользуетесь _mm_store_sd. Эта функция (прочитайте описание), сразу кладёт два double по указанному адресу. Попробуйте завести массив s[2], записать в него и потом сложить s[0]+s[1]. Всегда читайте описание функций перед использованием.

Comment: Странно, но если делать так : `double ss[2];
 _mm_store_sd(ss, s); 
 return ss[0] + ss[1];` , то нехватает половины произведения

Comment: @Евгений, я же говорю, учитесь читать документации к функциям. Я, вот, например, ошибся, что эта функция пишет два double по адресу, а вы не захотели меня проверить. Это делает другая функция. Попробуйте, пожалуйста, найти её сами. Это очень просто сделать. Подскажу: разница в названии будет в одной букве.

Comment: Сделал вот так  `_mm_store_pd(ss, s); 
 return ss[0] + ss[1];` Теперь результат верный, но ошибка с памятью так и осталась

Comment: В чём именно ошибка? Возможно, она в другом месте. Нужно изучать, а у меня ваш код всё равно не запустится.

Comment: Сложно сказать, в тестовом проекте где просто перемножаю два вектора, все работает. Как только вставляю эту же функцию в рабочий проект, где необходимо перемножать части массивов, функция    `_mm_mul_pd` обращается в запрещенные разделы памяти. Буду разбираться, но что-то неверно именно в умножении, ибо остальная часть проекта отлажена и с обычным умножением все работает

Comment: В таком случае (раз я не могу протестировать у себя), можете пойти двумя путями: либо ошибка в том, что ss не выровнен по 16 байт, как того требует многие функции (значит надо выровнять), либо используйте тот же приём, что в вашем примере: соберите сумму в xmm регистрах и заберите оттуда потом одно число. Это уже гарантированно должно сработать.

Answer (score 2):

А теперь напишите это на обычном дубовом C++ с циклами и сравните производительность. Я не думаю, что на такой ерунде, как скалярное произведение, вы окажетесь умнее компилятора.*

---

*Если вашему компилятору не вторая пятилетка от релиза пошла, разумеется.

Comment: Только компилятору флагами надо явно разрешить генерацию SSE команд.

Comment: @Arhad - Visual Studio  даже на дефолтных настройках оптимизации под релиз (/O2) это делает.